# Bought new Mobo, CPU and RAM. Freezes with dedicated Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, bios, freeze

So I have bought a new MoBo, CPU nad RAM. When I start windows with the MoBo's integrated graphics card, it works totally fine. But when I put the videocard (Radeon 5670) in and connect the cable to it, the computer freezes at the MoBo's welcome screen, I can't even enter BIOS. The Graphics Card's fan is spinning.

- CPU: AMD FX-8300
- MoBo: Asus M5A78L-M/USB3
- RAM: 8GB 1866 Mhz
- Videocard: Radeon 5670
- PSU: Logic 500W

Please help! ^^'

Comment: Check MOBO for LED used for DC OK if exist.  Perhaps 12V dips on boot.

Comment: Double and triple check you have the correct cables / the card seated correctly on the mobo, also, try booting with integrated graphics and updating the Mobo.

Comment: "and updating the Mobo" <sic> firmware

Answer (score 0):

Succeed to make it work by setting the Integrated Graphics in BIOS to PCI-GFX0-GPP-IGFX. Although it doesn't work with integrated graphics anymore at this settings, now works with the dedicated Graphics Card. ^^'